# Unity 5.3 onClick with parameters issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

In my game I programmatically create a bunch of buttons for a level select screen, and my intention was to have their onClick fire a function with a parameter that corresponds to level number.

Pseudocode:

```
public class UIManager extends MonoBehaviour {
    public var button : Transform;

    public function Start() {
        for(var i : int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var level : int = i + 1;
            var b : Transform = Instantiate(button);

            b.GetComponent(UI.Button).onClick.AddListener(function(){
                StartGame(level);
            });
        }
    }

    public function StartGame(level : int) {
        Debug.Log(level);
    }
}
```

However, in this situation, when any of these buttons is pressed, the console shows number 10.

How can I achieve what I'm aiming for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at how anonymous functions in JavaScript capture outer variables.

You are creating 10 anonymous functions in your for-loop. All these functions refer to the local variable `level`. However, they do not yet create their own scope for this variable until they are first called. This means, there is not 10 `level` locals, but only one until the first function is actually called. Only then will the current value of `level` be evaluated. And this will be the value it was assigned last: 10.

To get around this you'll have to force creation of a new scope during every iteration of the loop:

```
public class UIManager extends MonoBehaviour
{
    public var button : Transform;

    public function Start()
    {
        for(var i : int = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var level : int = i + 1;
            var b : Transform = Instantiate(button);

            b.GetComponent(UI.Button).onClick.AddListener
            (
                (function(newLocalLevel)
                {
                    return function()
                    {
                        StartGame(newLocalLevel);
                    };
                }) (level)
            );
        }
    }

    public function StartGame(level : int)
    {
        Debug.Log(level);
    }
}
```

I changed your direct assigned of an anonymous handler function to a factory function call, which takes the current (!) value of `level` as a parameter. As it is immediately executed, the factory function creates its own scope, with an own local called `newLocalLevel` that carries the correct value of `level`.

The factory function now creates and returns your anonymous handler function, which, even though it not yet creates its own scope, refers to the local `newLocalLevel` of the enclosing factory function, which has one seperate scope for every iteration of the loop.

See also http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62.